# What's the subscript for the last sample, if $m$ sampled from $n$ with replacement and without ordering?

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Source: p. 25 on the page = p. 41 of 288 in the PDF.  *[Lecture Notes in Applied Probability](https://www.acsu.buffalo.edu/~bialas/EAS305/305Notes.html)*.

Please see the screenshot beneath that I can't reproduce with MathJAX.

1. Am I right that $k_n$ means the $n$th ball drawn?
2. Please see the question beneath. Because $m$ (which can $> n$) is the number of drawings, shouldn't the last drawn ball be $k_m$?

> [image]

Comment: Please fix your title, because the question is about the section in the book, which is about "Sampling with replacement and without ordering".

Comment: @user8734617 Thanks. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes, $k_i$ will be the *label* of the $i$th ball that you draw. For example if you draw three balls and they are "5", "2", and "4", then $(k_1,k_2,k_3)=(5,2,4)$.
2. Yes, that is a typo, it should be $k_1,\ldots, k_m$.